# Can AI-written text detection be made more accurate if you know the prompt?

Tags: generative-model, anomaly-detection

Usually, genAI detection is of the form:

- Input: text.
- Output: was it generated by AI?

Thus far, AI-written text detection is [terribly inaccurate](https://openai.com/blog/new-ai-classifier-for-indicating-ai-written-text), and if you're a user of [r/ChatGPT](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/), you've probably seen myriad "my teacher accused me of plagiarism" posts as a result.

However, if we wanted to e.g. check if a Stack Overflow answer was AI generated, we might instead have the situation:

- Input: text and prompt (i.e., the Stack Overflow question).
- Output: was it generated by AI?

This seems like it would be a big advantage in detecting AI text.  I remember when I was trying to determine if an answer is or isn't AI-generated, copy/pasting the question into ChatGPT and comparing ChatGPT's answer with the posted answer was quite enlightening.

**Question**: Can AI-written text detection be made more accurate if you know the prompt?

I'm wondering if there's a research paper in this direction.  I didn't immediately find the answer to this question by [Googling the title](https://www.google.com.hk/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=Can+genAI+detection+be+made+more+accurate+if+you+know+the+prompt%3F).